# CSS Inheritance - Why is a 'later' declaration being overwritten by an 'earlier' one?

Tags: html, inheritance, text, css, overriding

I'm new to `html` and `CSS` but through the recent work I've been doing I thought I was getting a hold of how CSS works.. And it seemed to work kind of like scope in a language like Java.

My understanding was that, like Java, the declaration with the narrowest scope wins.. aka the most specific declaration would override its inherited versions, allowing you to, like I am trying to do, declare a set pattern for a group of objects and then if one of those needs a slightly different setting you can simply override the general rule for that one item.

However, I'm getting the feeling this is not the case, here I have a tabbed content box I'm working on;

The `html`:

```
<div id="feature-tabs">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#What We Do">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a id="large" href="#What Makes Us Different">What Makes Us Different</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Our Background">Our Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Why We Do It">Why We Do It</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And of course I labelled the one list-item as "large" so that I could force its width to be a little wider so it can fit on one line.

The `CSS`:

```
ul#tabs li a {
    width: 144px;           //TRYING TO OVERRIDE THIS DECLARATION
    height: 33px;
    color: #42454a; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
    a#large {
        width: 155px;          //WITH THIS ONE
        display: block;
    }
```

What is happening is that the width of `a"large"` is being overwritten by `a`. (144px not 155px)

So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do here-override an inherited trait?
2. Is it possible to simply vertically align each of the 4 tab's text to be centered? (This would make up for the ugly look I'm getting from the one button being two lines, where the rest are just one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade). The order in which the CSS is encountered is only used as a final resort.

Both selectors have the same media type.

Both selectors have the same importance and origin.

The specificity of your selectors are different

```
ul#tabs li a         a=0 b=1 c=0 d=3
a#large              a=0 b=1 c=0 d=1
```

The top one is more specific, so it's the one that will get used.

But if you used `ul#tabs li a#large`, it would get selected because it has the highest specificity.

```
ul#tabs li a#large   a=0 b=2 c=0 d=3
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS specifications define some 'rules of specificity' that determine which properties override others. [This article](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) covers the basics of it.

The selector `ul#tabs li a` is more specific than `a#large` and therefore the properties from `a#large` that are also in the other ruleset are ignored.

One workaround is to use `!important`:

```
a#large {
    width: 155px !important; // !important gives this property precedence
    display: block;
}
```